# Google Chrome: increase text size instead of zoom?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extensions

Firefox has a "Zoom Text Only" setting, if the width of a webpage is just right, but the text is too small.  IIRC, this used to be normal in web browsers... not anymore.

Is it possible to do this in Chrome?

I am aware of the [Font Size Increase](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ombpcpigmndepfckcifdblemkabaoihk) extension, but it's not customizable, and the reviews are bad.

Comment: I think this is a good question. It is about function and accessibility, not a product/extension recommendation. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s an extension for chrome called [*Zoom Text Only*](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zoom-text-only/jamhfhbppcmkgghlkeieococonlbppjg) which changes the size of only text, and preserves image sizes and webpage layout.

It adds the following hotkeys to zoom (only text):

```
Increase font size: Alt + -
Decrease font size: Alt + =
Reset    font size: Alt + 0
```

It leaves all of Chrome’s regular zooming functionality alone, so the following hotkeys still work as before:

```
Zoom out  : Ctrl + - / Ctrl Mouse-Wheel Up
Zoom in   : Ctrl + = / Ctrl Mouse-Wheel Down
Reset zoom: Ctrl + 0
```

It changes all the fonts on a page without changing the website’s spacing, as seen below.

As a plus for anyone who might be interested, there’s even a link to the source-code on GitHub from the extension’s Chrome Web Store page.

Before:

[image: Before zooming with the Zoom Text Only extension]

After:

[image: After zooming with the Zoom Text Only extension]

Comment: This works for me!  I thought I'd never have an answer to that one.  Thanks!

Comment: My eyes suck so I need to view fonts large when I'm doing a lot of reading in the browser, but as a web dev I also need to be able to switch back quickly to see the page in it's default format.  Thanks for making my life better.

Answer (score 2):

Totally ripped off from [here](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=96810):

> How to set the font size for all webpages
>   You can adjust the size of text on webpages.
>
> - Click the wrench icon  on the browser toolbar.
> - Select Settings.
> - Click Show advanced settings.
> - In the "Web Content" section, use the "Font size" drop-down menu to make adjustments.
>
> Some websites prevent the browser from changing just text size. For those sites, Chrome won’t be able to adjust the font size.

Comment: I'm not looking to change the default setting for font size browser-wide.  Instead, in older browsers, pressing Cmd + actually made the font size larger... I'd like to replicate this in Chrome.  This is great for laptop monitors.